Undecidability problem by Rice Theorem
I am studying complexity theory and I have problem with understanding some concepts about it. Can anyone help me please?
I have some problems with Rice Theorem. It says let $C$ be a class of partially decidable languages, let $L_C= \{<M> | L(M) \in C \}$. Then $L_C$ is decidable iff $C$ is either empty or contain all partially decidable languages.
Regarding this,
In proving undecidability using Rice Theorem, firstly, we provide an example which is not in $L_C$ and another one which is in $L_C$. This is to prove, the language is not trivial which makes sense. However, when we say let $A$ and $B$ be two languages that $L(A)= L(B)$, then both should have property $C$ or none of them have this property. What are we proving here? I mean why we do this?
Secondly, as we know, all finite languages are decidable. On the other hand, we can simply use Rice Theorem to prove that the class of finite languages are undecidable. How is it possible? How does it make sense that each member of a class is decidable, but considering the class, it will be undecidable?
My third question is not about Rice theorem but about concept of decidability itself. By definition, a language $L$ is decidable if there is a TM M that for any input $x$, it always halt and decides whether it accept or reject it. Based on this definition, we can say that all NP problems are decidable by defining a TM that for any input x, accept whenever the answer is a 'yes' and rejects whenever the answer is a 'no'. But, can we also say that decidable languages are in NP class? Because the NP problems are the ones that are verifiable in polynomial time and to me, and this is what a TM is doing for decidable languages. Is it true? If not, what am I getting wrong here?
My last question is what is difference between Solvability and Decidability? And when they have the same meaning?
Any answer to one of these questions would be really helpful and I really appreciate it.


How does it make sense that each member of a class is decidable, but considering the class, it will be undecidable?


As your third question says, each member of the class is decidable means: if $L$ is in our class, we have a TM deciding it. But can you think of any way to use these TMs to help decide if an arbitrary language is in our class? I can't. Note their inputs are different as well.
Does the opposite also seem confusing: the class of all languages is of course decidable (the decision procedure is just returning "yes" for every program), but it contains many undecidable languages?
This is even a further analogy, but is it confusing that there can be an infinite set of finite sets or a finite set of infinite sets?


that all NP problems are decidable by defining a TM that for any input x, accept whenever the answer is a 'yes' and rejects whenever the answer is a 'no'

But how do you find if the answer is "yes" or "no"? Since the problem is NP, there is a verifying TM but it doesn't just take $x$ as its input, it needs a certificate as well. It's true that all NP problems are decidable, but your argument isn't sufficient.

But, can we also say that decidable languages are in NP class? Because the NP problems are the ones that are verifiable in polynomial time and to me, and this is what a TM is doing for decidable languages.

No, a language is decidable means that a program deciding it exists. But it can take much more than polynomial time.
